# Caption titles in List of tables and List of figures overlapping subsection number

Tags: table-of-contents

I need to show the numbering of my tables and figures up to subsection which makes the numbering have four digits (e.g. Table 1.2.3.4). When I create the List of tables or the List of figures the title of the caption overlaps with the last digit of numbering.

See image:

[image: overlapping description]

I only find ways to add vertical space between entries, but not to add horizontal space within the entry. Any idea would be appreciated, especially if it doesn't change the spacing of the ToC.

MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, oneside]{report}

\usepackage{chngcntr} % to be able to change the numbering "depth"
    \counterwithin{figure}{subsection} % make figures show subsection number
    \counterwithin{table}{subsection} % make tables show subsection number

\begin{document}

\listoftables
\newpage


\chapter{chap1}
\section{sec1.1}
\subsection{subsec1.1.1}

\begin{table}[!htb]
\centering
\caption{caption.}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\hline
Hola & Hello & Hallo \\ 
Adéu & Bye   & Tchüs \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[!htb]
\centering
\caption{caption.}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\hline
Hola & Hello & Hallo \\ 
Adéu & Bye   & Tchüs \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[!htb]
\centering
\caption{caption.}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\hline
Hola & Hello & Hallo \\ 
Adéu & Bye   & Tchüs \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Take a look at the `tocloft` package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `tocloft` package as below.

```
% lotnumprob.tex  SE 554603
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, oneside]{report}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\setlength{\cfttabnumwidth}{3.5em}
\setlength{\cftfignumwidth}{3.5em}

\usepackage{chngcntr} % to be able to change the numbering "depth"
    \counterwithin{figure}{subsection} % make figures show subsection number
    \counterwithin{table}{subsection} % make tables show subsection number

\begin{document}

\listoftables
\newpage


\chapter{chap1}
\section{sec1.1}
\subsection{subsec1.1.1}

\begin{table}[!htb]
\centering
\caption{caption.}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\hline
Hola & Hello & Hallo \\ 
Adéu & Bye   & Tchüs \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[!htb]
\centering
\caption{caption.}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\hline
Hola & Hello & Hallo \\ 
Adéu & Bye   & Tchüs \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[!htb]
\centering
\caption{caption.}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\hline
Hola & Hello & Hallo \\ 
Adéu & Bye   & Tchüs \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Change the `3.5em` to suit your design.